# Como fazer para julgar todos os números digitados? Apenas o último está sendo julgado e exibido

Tags: c

@Edit gente não pode usar vetores somente for, while e do while :x

Fiz esse código mas no final quando e para exibir os números que eu digitei ele so ta aparecendo o ultimo numero digitado ao invés de todos, oque eu devo arrumar ?

Questão: Um número é, por definição, primo se ele não tem divisores , exceto 1 e ele próprio. Preparar um programa em C para ler vários números e determinar se
cada um dele é primo ou não.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main (){
int a, b, num, q, quantidade, primo;

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

printf ("Quantos número deseja ser informado: ");
scanf ("%d", &quantidade);

for (q=1; q<=quantidade; q++){
    printf ("Digite um número: ");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
}

for (a=1; a<=quantidade; a++){
    primo=0;
    for(b=1; b<=quantidade; b++)
        if((a % b) == 0)
            primo++;
    if (primo == 2) printf ("%d É PRIMO.\n", num);
    else printf ("%d NÃO É PRIMO.\n", num);
}
}
```

Comment: Como responderam o ideal é colocar os valores digitados em uma lista e depois percorrer ela. Fiz um exemplo que você pode verificar aqui https://repl.it/Mdxj/2

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar mas não pode usar vetor, somente for, while e do while :x

Comment: Posso sugerir uma edição de título? "Como fazer para julgar todos os números digitados? Apenas o último está sendo julgado e exibido"

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pronto :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não pode utilizar vetores, que seria a melhor solução para o problema, pode passar a lógica de verificação de primo para dentro do `while` que lê os números.

Pode também fazer alguns ajustes no próprio laço de verificação do primo, que o tornam mais simples e mais eficiente:

```
printf ("Quantos número deseja ser informado: ");
scanf ("%d", &quantidade);

for (q=1; q<=quantidade; q++)
{
    printf ("Digite um número: ");
    scanf ("%d",&num);

    //a lógica de verificação do primo vem agora aqui, à medida que lê cada numero
    primo=0;

    //agora começa em 2 e termina em num-1, verificando menos 2 elementos sempre
    for (a=2; a<num; a++) 
    {
        if(num % a == 0){
            primo++; 
            break; //se deu para dividir por um já não precisa de ver mais
        }
    }

    //agora testa com 0 e não 2 devido ao ajuste do for
    if (primo == 0) printf ("%d É PRIMO.\n", num);
    else printf ("%d NÃO É PRIMO.\n", num);
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/n7CZI0)

**Organização com funções**

Melhor ainda seria organizar a lógica de verificação do primo numa função à parte:

```
int ePrimo(int n){
    int a;
    for (a=2; a<n; a++)
    {
        if(n % a == 0){
            return 0; //agora fica mais simples pois basta retornar
        }
    }

    return 1; //se chegou ao fim é primo
}

int main ()
{
    int num, q, quantidade;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf ("Quantos número deseja ser informado: ");
    scanf ("%d", &quantidade);

    for (q=1; q<=quantidade; q++)
    {
        printf ("Digite um número: ");
        scanf ("%d",&num);

        //aqui agora apenas mostra o resultado da função ePrimo
        printf("%d %s.\n",num, ePrimo(num)? "É PRIMO": "NÃO É PRIMO");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/J8PtZi)

**Melhorias de eficiência na verificação de Primo**

Assim como o @JeffersonQuesado indicou nos comentários, ainda tem margem para melhorar a parte da pesquisa do primo com algumas alterações especificas:

- Pesquisar apenas enquanto o numero corrente é menor ou igual que a raiz quadrada do limite, pois a partir daí temos garantia que não haverá nenhum divisível.
- Se o numero não é par e por isso não é divisível por 2, também não será divisível por nenhum outro par.

Considerando essas melhorias a função de verificação ficaria assim:

```
int ePrimo(int n)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0) return 0; //se for pair sai logo como não primo

    int a, limite = sqrt(n); //calcula o limite com a raiz quadrada do numero

    for (a=3; a<=limite; a+=2) //agora anda de 2 em 2 excluindo todos os pares
    {
        if(n % a == 0)
        {
            return 0; //agora fica mais simples pois basta retornar
        }
    }

    return 1; //se chegou ao fim é primo
}
```

Comment: Ficou muito bom bem explicado, brigadão esclareceu bastante coisa :D

Comment: Você poderia deixar a busca pelo primo mais rápida se por `for (a = 2; a*a <= n; a++)` no lugar da iteração atual. Também é possível reduzir à metade o espaço de pesquisa se levar em conta que se for par, é divisível por 2, não precisando checar nenhum outro número par

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Correto! Agradeço o comentário. Irei adicionar essas dicas para que a resposta fique mais completa

Answer (score 1):

A variável "num" deve ser um vetor, experimenta mudar depois do primeiro SCANF para:

```
     int num[quantidade];
```

E restruturar o código para tal.

Answer (score 0):

Resposta direta: Você tem que verificar se o número é primo antes de atualizar a variável `num`.
...
Quando o teu primeiro `for` é executado, ele fica lendo números e salvando na variável `num`. Porém, ao ler o valor, não acontece nada. Quando o teu `for` chega no fim, a tua variável `num` fica com o último valor digitado.